# How do you unpack a python object with a list of tuples as the return value?

Tags: python

So I'm getting a repsonse back from an application.

When I write the below to a file I get

```
f.write(str(request.packet))
```

```
AuthPacket([(1, [username']), (2,
[b'\11?']), (5,
[b'23']), (30, [b'8.8.8.8']), (31,
[b'4.4.4.4']), (61, [b'4.4.4.4']), (66,
[b'4.4.4.4']), ((9, 1), [b'iPhone',
b'mdm-tlv=device-phone-id=unknown',
b'mdm-tlv=device-platform=apple-ios',
b'mdm-tlv=device-platform-version=16.2',
b'mdm-tlv=device-uid=xx',
b'mdm-tlv=device-uid-global=xx',
b'mdm-tlv=ac-user-agent=xxxx (iPhone)
5.0.00246', b'audit-session-id=ac11036711153000643443dd', b'ip:source-ip=xx', b'coa-push=true']), (4,
[b'kfkdkfld']), ((3076, 146), [b'xx']), ((3076, 150),
[b'xxxx'])])
```

```
    f.write('\n\n')
    for x,x1 in request.packet:
        f.write(str(x))
        f.write(str(x1))
        f.write('\n\n')
```

I'm getting an error of

```
for x,x1 in request.packet:
        builtins.TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

If I just iterate through X I'll get the first value of the tuple returned and nothing else..so I'm bit confused how to deal with this and get the second values of each tuple in the list in the object.

Comment: Read the documentation for this object.

Comment: Can you print `request.packet` more readably? Like `pprint.pprint(request.packet)`?

Comment: instead of converting the object to string, check any option available to convert an object to json or some other format

Comment: You can't treat all of the elements identically.  You will have to look at each one.  It LOOKS like the second item in each tuple is a list (of length 1) of byte strings, so that should be easy.to handle.  HOWEVER, you need to read the docs to see if iterating through `request.packet` gives you the same structure as the `str` of `request.packet`.  What module is this from?

Comment: @TimRoberts Duo Authentication.. using the Pyrad libraries.

Comment: And have you read ANY of the documentation?  The `AuthPacket` acts like a standard Python map.  You can enumerate it using `for key,value in request.packet.items():`.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for the direction I'm normally in PHP land so python Map is a bit foreign to me...but I appreciate the direction.

Comment: A Python `map` is almost exactly the same as a PHP array.  Keys map to values.